Required textarea field is not appropriately scrolled to when using fixed header. CSS property scroll-margin/padding does not work
I have a fixed header on my website and a form. There are some input fields and some textarea fields that are required. When the form is submitted without those fields filled, I would like the user to be appropriately scrolled to the top-most required field that is not filled. The sticky navbar makes that tricky - I have figured out a solution for the input tags - using the CSS property scroll-margin-top with a value equal to that of the height of the navbar. Unfortunately, that DOES NOT work for the textarea tags.
header {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 0;
}

input { /* WORKS */
  scroll-margin-top: 50px;
}

textarea { /* DOES NOT WORK */
  scroll-margin-top: 50px;
}

Here is a fiddle displaying the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/3t42yqgj/ (Make sure to open it with Chrome or another browser based on it).
One solution is to set the CSS property scroll-padding-top (note the use of padding instead of margin) of the html tag with a value equal to that of the height of the navbar. The problem with that is that it introduces issues with other parts of my website - I would like this to be applied only to the forms of a few particular pages. Unfortunately, the property DOES NOT work on any other tag (e.g form or div).
html { /* WORKS */
  scroll-padding-top: 50px;
}

form { /* DOES NOT WORK */
  scroll-padding-top: 50px;
}

div { /* DOES NOT WORK */
  scroll-padding-top: 50px;
}

Please, help me!

Try changing the the value of textarea in the CSS .Increase it because the distance of the textarea field is more than from the top.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
